# Declaring elements without them being inside a function

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys am having trouble with this, When I declare the elements outside the loop the script ends up being broken. I plan to use the elements in several functions. Tried a lot of times but didn't find a solution. Broke the project a few times while doing guess work. Also If there's any idea on how to shorten this or to make it work better please give me a heads up :)

```
async function loadTable() {
    try {
        while(dpTable.firstChild) dpTable.removeChild(dpTable.firstChild);
        const result = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/student_data', { method: 'GET' });
        const table = await result.json();
        table.forEach((res) => {
            //Create Table elements and then load results into the elements
            const tr = document.createElement('tr');
            const studentNo = document.createElement('td');
            const name = document.createElement('td');
            const surname = document.createElement('td');
            const date_joined = document.createElement('td');
            const fees_paid = document.createElement('td');
            const fees_owing = document.createElement('td');
            const is_owing = document.createElement('td');
            const trash_btn = document.createElement('button');
            const trash_Icon = document.createElement('i');
            
            tr.id = 'Content';
            studentNo.id = res.id;
            name.id = 'fname';
            surname.id = 'lname';
            fees_paid.id = 'amount_paid';
            fees_owing.id = 'amount_owing';
            is_owing.id = 'debt';


            //Enter the data from the response
            studentNo.innerText = res.id;
            name.innerText = res.fname;
            surname.innerText = res.lname;
            fees_paid.innerText = res.amount_paid;
            fees_owing.innerText = res.amount_owing;
            date_joined.innerText = res.date_joined;
            is_owing.innerText = res.is_owing;
            trash_btn.innerText = 'Delete';

            //Add Classes for elements
            studentNo.classList.add('trContent');
            name.classList.add('trContent');
            surname.classList.add('trContent');
            fees_paid.classList.add('trContent');
            fees_owing.classList.add('trContent');
            date_joined.classList.add('trContent');
            is_owing.classList.add('trContent');
            trash_Icon.classList.add('fas');
            trash_Icon.classList.add('fa-trash');
            trash_Icon.classList.add('trash-btn');

            //Append table row elements to main table
            tr.append(studentNo);
            tr.append(name);
            tr.append(surname);
            tr.append(fees_paid);
            tr.append(fees_owing);
            tr.append(date_joined);
            tr.append(is_owing);
            tr.append(trash_btn);

            //Event Listeners
            trash_btn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
                if (window.confirm('Delete')) {
                    console.log('trash icon clicked');
                    const jsonReq = {};
                    jsonReq.id = res.id;
                    const result = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/student_data', {
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
                        body: JSON.stringify(jsonReq),
                    });

                    alert('Deleted Record');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });

            //Append the table as a child to the main element
            dpTable.appendChild(tr);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Cant load List ${e}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"the script ends up being broken"` - can you explain in what way that is the case?

Comment: You are creating the elements in a loop, so it doesn't make any sense to make them global and use them elsewhere, as only the result of the last iteration would be available. This sounds like an XY problem, what do you want to ultimately achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of minor issues you need to remedy or perhaps even ignore

1. Element IDs must be unique so you can't use the same id for multiple cells. You could switch to using classNames instead
2. The buttons need to be inserted into cells, they can't be directly insterted into a row

You can cut this all down quite a bit by using an array of field names to iterate and using `TableElement.insertRow()` and `TableRow.insertCell()`

Something like:

```
const fields = ['studentNo','fname','lname','amount_paid','amount_owing','date_joined','is_owing'] ;

table.forEach((res) => {
  const row = dpTable.insertRow();
  // loop over fields array to create cell for each
  fields.forEach((f) => {
    const cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerText = res[f];
    cell.className = 'trContent';
  });

  const btnCell = row.insertCell();// cell for button
  const trash_btn = document.createElement('button');
  const trash_Icon = document.createElement('i');
  trash_Icon.classList.add('fas', 'fa-trash', 'trash-btn');
  trash_btn.append(trash_icon);
  btnCell.append(trash_btn);// insert button in own cell

  trash_btn.addEventListener('click', .....);
});
```

Comment: Thanks will try it out, am always looking for way to improve the way I code dont like writing hundreds of lines that I really dont need :)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely because you're declaring them as `const` which  means they shouldn't be rewritten - but you have them in a loop which reassigns them and so causes an error. You can use `let` instead in this case

```
async function loadTable() {
    try {
        while(dpTable.firstChild) dpTable.removeChild(dpTable.firstChild);
        const result = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/student_data', { method: 'GET' });
        const table = await result.json();
        let tr, studentNo, name, surname, date_joined, fees_paid, fees_owing, is_owing, trash_btn, trash_Icon
        table.forEach((res) => {
            //Create Table elements and then load results into the elements
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            studentNo = document.createElement('td');
            name = document.createElement('td');
            surname = document.createElement('td');
            date_joined = document.createElement('td');
            fees_paid = document.createElement('td');
            fees_owing = document.createElement('td');
            is_owing = document.createElement('td');
            trash_btn = document.createElement('button');
            trash_Icon = document.createElement('i');
            
            tr.id = 'Content';
            studentNo.id = res.id;
            name.id = 'fname';
            surname.id = 'lname';
            fees_paid.id = 'amount_paid';
            fees_owing.id = 'amount_owing';
            is_owing.id = 'debt';


            //Enter the data from the response
            studentNo.innerText = res.id;
            name.innerText = res.fname;
            surname.innerText = res.lname;
            fees_paid.innerText = res.amount_paid;
            fees_owing.innerText = res.amount_owing;
            date_joined.innerText = res.date_joined;
            is_owing.innerText = res.is_owing;
            trash_btn.innerText = 'Delete';

            //Add Classes for elements
            studentNo.classList.add('trContent');
            name.classList.add('trContent');
            surname.classList.add('trContent');
            fees_paid.classList.add('trContent');
            fees_owing.classList.add('trContent');
            date_joined.classList.add('trContent');
            is_owing.classList.add('trContent');
            trash_Icon.classList.add('fas');
            trash_Icon.classList.add('fa-trash');
            trash_Icon.classList.add('trash-btn');

            //Append table row elements to main table
            tr.append(studentNo);
            tr.append(name);
            tr.append(surname);
            tr.append(fees_paid);
            tr.append(fees_owing);
            tr.append(date_joined);
            tr.append(is_owing);
            tr.append(trash_btn);

            //Event Listeners
            trash_btn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
                if (window.confirm('Delete')) {
                    console.log('trash icon clicked');
                    const jsonReq = {};
                    jsonReq.id = res.id;
                    const result = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/student_data', {
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
                        body: JSON.stringify(jsonReq),
                    });

                    alert('Deleted Record');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });

            //Append the table as a child to the main element
            dpTable.appendChild(tr);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Cant load List ${e}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even tried using let still had the same problem, even tried using bare declaration nothing worked :(

Comment: Even tried using let still had the same problem, even tried using bare declaration nothing worked :(. For example I have a alert const declared maybe at the top of the code, which I would call inside a function later on. Instead of the alert being called inside a function its the one that gets called first as soon as the page/file loads.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely simplify your code and make it more flexible into the process. The JSON data returned will have a set of keys - these can be used to build the HTML output without knowing, in advance, what they are. The beauty of that is the same code can display greatly different datasets very easily.

If you were to use the method `create` shown below to create the new DOM elements you greatly reduce the code needed.

```
<?php
    #---------------------------------------------------
    # to emulate whatever "users/student_data" returns.
    # this is dummy data for example only.
    #
    
    set_include_path('c:/wwwroot/dbo/');
    require 'db-conn-details.php';
    require 'mysqli-conn.php';
    
    
    /*
        When we receive the AJAX request, identified by querystring,
        prepare some sql statement and execute. Return the full
        recordset in JSON format.
    */
    if( isset( $_GET['fetch'] ) && $_GET['fetch']=='data' ){
        ob_clean();
        $sql='select * from `sport` limit 10';
        $res=$db->query( $sql );
        $json=json_encode( $res->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) );
        exit( $json );
    }
    
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='DELETE' ){
        exit('DELETE');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #data{ border:1px solid grey;display:table;padding:1rem;width:100%; }
        </style>
        <script>
        
            // The endpoint used by the ajax query - in this example it is same page.
            const url=location.href; //http://localhost:5000/users/student_data
            
            const create=function(t,a,p){
                /*
                    utility to add a new node with attributes and content.
                    t=type ~ the DOM node type, defaults to DIV
                    a=attrbutes to set
                    p=parent to append new node to.
                */
                let el=(typeof(t)=='undefined'||t==null)?document.createElement('div'):document.createElement(t);
                let _arr=['innerHTML','innerText','html','text'];
                for(let x in a)if(a.hasOwnProperty(x)&&!~_arr.indexOf(x))el.setAttribute(x,a[x]);
                if(a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML')||a.hasOwnProperty('html'))el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML||a.html;
                if(a.hasOwnProperty('innerText')||a.hasOwnProperty('text'))el.innerText=a.innerText||a.text;
                if(p!=null )typeof(p)=='object'?p.appendChild(el):document.getElementById(p).appendChild(el);
                return el;
            };
            
            
            
            async function loadTable() {
                try {
                
                    // It was not clear where dbTable was defined - hence declared here
                    const dpTable=document.querySelector('table#data');
                    
                    while( dpTable.firstChild ) dpTable.removeChild( dpTable.firstChild );
                    // As this example targets the same page I needed a way to return only db results - hence using querystring.
                    const result = await fetch( url + '?fetch=data' );
                    const json = await result.json();
                    
                    // the callback that will process the button clicks. The button has a dataset attribute set
                    // that will use the res.id value from each JSON record.
                    const clickhandler=async function(e){
                        if( window.confirm('Delete') ) {
                            const jsonReq = {
                                id:this.dataset.id
                            };
                            const result = await fetch( url, {
                                method: 'DELETE',
                                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                                body: JSON.stringify( jsonReq ),
                            });
                            console.log( result );
                            
                            alert('Record deleted');
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    };
                    
                    
                    json.forEach( res => {
                        // find all the keys from the JSON ~ one of which will be the ID for the record ( res.id )
                        let fields=Object.keys( res );
                        
                        // generate new table row
                        let tr=dpTable.insertRow();
                        
                        // iterate through all json keys - add new table cell with JSON data.
                        fields.forEach( field => {
                            create('td',{
                                'data-id':field,
                                text:res[field]
                            },tr);
                        });
                        
                        // add the button for the row and assign listener - also assign the dataset attribute for the record ID.
                        let bttn=create('button',{ text:'Delete','data-id':res.id }, tr.insertCell() );
                            bttn.addEventListener( 'click', clickhandler );
                            
                        // add the icon to the button
                        create('i',{ 'class':'fas fa-trash trash-btn' }, bttn );                
                    });
                    
                    
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log('Unable to load list: %o',e);
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',loadTable);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='data'></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The sql query shown here in the demo returns the following data:

```
[
    {"id":"1","tag":"3D Archery","description":"a form of archery in which  the goal is to strike  targets in the shape of animals at unknown distances.","enabled":"1"},
    {"id":"2","tag":"3x3","description":"a variation of basketball played on a half court with just three players in each team.","enabled":"1"},
    {"id":"3","tag":"Abseiling","description":"an adventure sport where the participants  descend  a steep formation using a rope. (not really a sport).","enabled":"1"},
    {"id":"4","tag":"Acroski","description":"athletes on snow skis perform various choreographed\u00c2\u00a0routines (once called Ski Ballet)","enabled":"1"},
    {"id":"5","tag":"Adventure Racing","description":"an event combining two or more endurance disciplines, such as Orienteering, Cross-Country Running, Mountain Biking, Paddling and Climbing. It is also called Expedition Racing.","enabled":"1"},
    {"id":"6","tag":"Aerials","description":"a freestyle skiing discipline  in which athletes ski along a take-off ramp, then perform various in-air tricks.","enabled":"1"},
    {"id":"7","tag":"Aerobatics","description":"sport aerobatics  involves aircraft maneuvers such as  rolls, loops, stall turns (hammerheads), and tailslides.","enabled":"1"},
    {"id":"8","tag":"Acrobatic Gymnastics","description":"team of gymnasts work together to perform acrobatic moves  in combination with dance moves.","enabled":"1"},
    {"id":"9","tag":"Aerobic Gymnastics","description":"another name for Sport Aerobics.","enabled":"1"},{"id":"10","tag":"Aeromodeling","description":"activity using remotely controlled flying model aircraft (not really a sport).","enabled":"1"}
]
```

And yielded the following output:
[image: Generated content]

Comment: Thanks for the advice though am using express, and postgresql for my project :)